# Get reference to target of event in d3 in high-level listener?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I made a put a click listener on an svg element using d3:

```
<svg height="100" width="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" id="a">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" id="b">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" id="c">
</svg>
```

Javascript:

```
d3.select('svg').on('click', function(d, i) {
  // Somehow console.log the ID of the circle clicked on (if any).
});
```

I'd like to refer to the circle that was clicked on (if any) in the handler. However, d3 does not give me a reference to the event. I know that I could just put a listener on every circle and not rely on the event bubbling to the `<svg>` element, but I don't want to do that since I plan to dynamically add more circles later and don't want to have to carefully add and remove listeners.

Comment: Are your circles really stacked on one another? If so, you are only going to click the last one (unless you used "pointer-events:none" on the previous ones.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [D3.js documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Selections.md#animation--interaction):

> "To access the current event within a listener, use the global [d3.event](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Selections.md#d3_event).

This allows you to access everything related to the event, including mouse position and event source/target (print `d3.event` in `console.log()`).

To get the ID you could:

```
d3.select('svg').on('click', function(d, i) {
    // Somehow console.log the ID of the circle clicked on (if any).
    console.log("Clicked ID: " + d3.event.target.id);
});
```

If the circles are stacked in the same position as in your example, the event will be caught by the *last* circle you added (unless you change its [pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) CSS property to `none`), since the previous ones will be hidden.